# What's app-root in this project?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm going on to start a Spring boot Restful project using [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to build a restful application and then [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) to add swagger2 to it. in [second link](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) it says somewhere that you can test swagger-ui in your browser by visiting "http://localhost:8080/your-app-root/swagger-ui.html". what 's app-root in my project? is it the name of project? my project's name is RestSpringBoot. and I tried "http://localhost:8080/RestSpringBoot/swagger-ui.html" . But I get following error:

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

UPDATE: I use intellij IDE and I have configured in Configurations to run my project with sring boot. when I run the project and check the url http://localhost:8080/ it gives the same error. but this one: http://localhost:8080/persons/all will return a json of users. Isn't it that spring boot has embedded tomcat in itself and because of that there is no need to start tomcat or deploy the project on tomcat? if it is true why by running the project via spring boot visiting http://localhost:8080 will give "Whitelabel Error Page" error.

UPDATE 2 : when my spring boot project is running i open this url : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html but i can't see list of controllers, instead i see this page:
[image: picture]

The thing I can't understand is that when my project is not running, again I see the same as above picture in http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

Answer (score 2):

There is no app-root in the project link you specified. As you can see /greeting endpoint is accessed using http://localhost:8080/greeting . So, use just this to reach your swagger ui. http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.
Regarding spring boot and whitelabel error page, The fact that you are seeing this page means that tomcat is running and it is telling you that it doesn't have any mapping for the url pattern you are trying(which is just '/'). You should add a controller and expose paths (using `RequestMapping`) which you want to use as done in the first link GreetingController class.

Comment: your explanation was helpful but by clicking on http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I can't see a list of controllers.  @pvpkiran

Comment: another question is if tomcat is running why i can't see tomcat homepage by visiting localhost:8080? you can check UPDATE 2

Comment: it is designed that way, since this is an embedded tomcat. You can change this behaviour, but doesn't make sense. Regarding earlier question couple of things  
1. If yor are seeing swagger page even when ur application is not running, that means the page is cached in the browser. just clear the cache or on incognito window and try.

Comment: 2. regarding endpoints not visible. Do you have any security for endpoints created in your application and have you done this bit mentioned in that tutorial about adding resourceHandlers to registry? If not do it and add one more line to that 
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

3. Do you see the json when you reach this url http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Comment: first I answer your 3rd question, yes I see the josn. now i can see the controllers in swagger-ui.html page by copying the configuration bean in main class which includes @SpringBootApplication, but i can't understand why it wasn't correct when swagger configuration was in a separate class as mentioned in the linked.

Comment: separate is class is ok. But that class needs to be annotated with one of the spring annotations. for example @ Configuration. In your main class you have @SpringBootApplication and hence it gets scanned.  If you put in other class you need to tell spring to scan it.

Comment: As you see in the link @ configuration was at the top of the swagger configuration class and I'd added it too and despite having @ configuration it wasn't working. @pvpkiran

Answer (score 0):

Just try : http://localhost:8080/RestSpringBoot/api/swagger-ui.html

I am assuming here that your project name is : RestSpringBoot

Comment: it gives this error again: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Apr 19 10:25:30 IRDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available @Pratik Shah